# Improper Neutralization of Script-Related HTML Tags in a Web Page (XSS)

Tags: java, veracode

Can anyone please help me in understanding what's wrong.

```
 @ResponseBody
 @RequestMapping(value = "/compare", method = RequestMethod.POST, 
                                     produces = { "application/json" })
    public List<A> compareDocument(HttpServletRequest request,
            @RequestBody B b) {

        C c = new C();
        c.setSourceContactCode(b.getTargetContactID());
        c.setSourceProfileID(b.getTargetProfileID());
        B b= this.Service.getAllPortfolio(c);
        List<A> targetDocument = b.getDocuments();
        return this.Service.compareDocument(b, targetDocument);
            }
```

The veracode is showing me error on :

```
         c.setSourceProfileID(b.getTargetProfileID());
```

B and C are Value Objects (Vo's) of which instances are JSON properties. All getter and setter method returns / uses String.

Answer (score 0):

(B) b object comes from request (user input), so Veracode considers it as untrusted data. Someone can put there script code which can be executed. For example:

```html
<script>alert('Collect data and send to my server or other actions');</script>
```

When you log this data and view through some html tool or put this data on site page it can be executed on load and lead to attacks. Veracode wants you to escape special characters like '<' and '>'.
It can be done with ESAPI tool, for example:

```
String encodedForHtml = ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTML(b.getTargetProfileID());
c.setSourceProfileID(encodedForHtml);
```

This will escape special characters and string will be printed as string but not as part of html page.